# preg_match_all not working in php but successfully tested in an online regex tester

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to match all lines in a string which start and end with a vertical bar "|". I have tried out different patterns and tested the pattern '/^\|.*\|$/m' successfully using the online tester https://regex101.com/.

However, when I put the same successfully tested pattern into my php script, it does not work. This is a sample code:

```
$re = '/^\|.*\|$/m';
$str = 'Why is this not working?

|Test|
|Test|
|Test|
|Test|
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
var_dump($matches);
```

This code outputs

```
array(0) {
}
```

which means the pattern did not find any match. It is driving me crazy. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When I copy&past your sample code it works fine. You can also see it [here](https://3v4l.org/1pIKt). I think something is wrong with your PHP install, or there are invisible characters in your sample that don't survive copy&paste.

Comment: It doesn't work on this site as well.. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e53334bbc16829c47cb8ccf9151941afbd1eaf3d

Comment: Include carriage return `\r?$`

Comment: Use `'/(*ANYCRLF)^\|.*\|$/m'`

Comment: Not worth an answer @WiktorStribiżew? Looks good, because it does not include the carriage return in the match, does it.

Comment: Its a bug in Php's version of PCRE. The standard multi-line mode `(?m)` used with `$` is supposed to correlate to `<here>(?:\r?\n|\r)` or `(?:\r?\n|\r)<here>` The CRLF translation is supposed to be independent of platform. Post a bug report for it. This means that Php can't be trusted anymore for EOL in multi-line mode. Kind of sad really. Further, what's really sad is that `.*` the _dot_ matches CR `\r` so that `.*` gets up to and including any CR on the line (try `(?m)^\|.*\|.$`. )http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4b1c26be142d64e6c3dbd89392b5a0dad2371276

Comment: `(?m)^\|.*\|.$` http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9c3c040c7611e6b00278bdbef0d908e4fa36173a

Answer (score 2):

With this regex should work

```
$re = '/^\|.*\|\r$/m';
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/44c7d929742a58ca81f9e7ffad4587d9a4854b15

Answer (score 2):

You may tell the PCRE engine to match the end of line before any of the vertical whitespace chars using the `(*ANY)` PCRE verb:

```
$re = '/(*ANY)^\|.*\|$/m';
```

See [PCRE docs](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt):

> `PCRE_NEWLINE_ANY`  specifies that any Unicode newline sequence should be recognized.

Note that for most cases, `(*ANYCRLF)` is enough since it will enable `.` to match any char but a CR and LF and `$` will match right before either of the chars.

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/SKrJt5):

```
$re = '/(*ANY)^\|.*\|$/m';
$str = "Why is this not working?\r\n\r\n|Test|\r\n|Test|\r\n|Test|\r\n|Test|\r\n";
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => |Test|
    [1] => |Test|
    [2] => |Test|
    [3] => |Test|
)
```

Comment: I've never seen (*ANY) in the wild. What's the problem with it @sln? What about `/^\|.*\|(?=\R)$/um`?

Comment: @wp78de [Your regex does not match](https://ideone.com/96o20W) because `$` matches only before `\n`, and between `|` and `\n` there is `\r` (hence the lookahead does not help). There is no problem with `(*ANY)` verb, because it helps override the newline flag PCRE was compiled with.

Comment: @wp78de - Almost `/^\|.*\|(?-m:(?=\R|$))/um` http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/73cdb63d1c78c51fbd5457913e830c2ac073deef But, it might be a Php quirk in the way their using PCRE. Like here https://regex101.com/r/2DPqEr/1 the sample seems to have CRLF endings, yet works as it should.

Comment: @sln regex101 always uses LF endings. You cannot test CRLF endings there.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Apparently, since `\r` doesn't match. It looks like a crappy website, trying to do auto-stripping of CR from the sample, ala Perl. Amazingly, Boost has no problem with treating `(?m)$` as either `<here>(?:\r?\n|\r)` or `(?:\r?\n|\r)<here>`. If inclined, would not try to defend PCRE _or_ Php for this egregious error. And, to whom ever deleted my comment before, take a pill and chill out. You're not helping the cause to fix regex engines.

Comment: @sln Take it easy, it is not a crusade (I hope)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - This is not a new issue, this has been ongoing for years. Still have to call them out for this problem when the usage arise, again and again and, ...