# Regex to match and extract North American phone numbers

Tags: php, regex, regex-group

I need to match and extract phone numbers from text ... phone numbers that are in this format:

```
589-845-2889

(589)-845-2889

589.845.2889

589 845 2889

5898452889

(589) 845 2889
```

The following operation matches the above with great accuracy:

```
preg_match_all("/(\()?\d{3}(?(1)\))[-. ]?\d{3}[-. ]?\d{4}/", $test, $result);
```

So I need to extend it to support international prefix, such as `1` or `+1`. Hence, it should also match `1(589) 845 2889`, `+1(589) 845 2889`, `1589 845 2889`, `1 589 845 2889`, `15898452889` , etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Include `(\+?1 ?)?` at the start?

Comment: What have you tried for supporting 1, +1?

Comment: Tried `(?:1(?:[. -])?)` but it only matches the ones with 1, +1. Excludes the others.

Comment: @Phil, thanks, works but fails on some edge cases like `+1207 244 7002` and `+1 207 244 7002`

Comment: Is this valid `(589) (845) (2889)`?

Comment: @nice_dev should not be

Comment: There are too many tests to check with. Better not to hunt for just a single regex but rather also take help of loops etc by splitting the 3 digit groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the example data, you might use:

```
^(?:\+?1\h*)?(?:(\()?\d{3}(?(1)\))[-. ]?\d{3}[-. ]?\d{4})$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:\+?1\h?)?` Optionally match 1 optionally prefixed by `+` or followed by a space
- `(\()?\d{3}(?(1)\))` Match 3 digits between parenthesis or not
- `[-. ]?` Match optional `-` `.`
- `\d{3}` Match 3 digits
- `[-. ]?` Match optional `-` `.`
- `\d{4}` Match 4 digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mf7u9I/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/rtNQt)

Example

```
$re = '/^(?:\+?1\h?)?(\()?\d{3}(?(1)\))([-. ]?)\d{3}\2\d{4}$/m';
$str = '589-845-2889
(589)-845-2889
589.845.2889
589 845 2889
5898452889
(589) 845 2889
1(589) 845 2889
+1(589) 845 2889
1589 845 2889
1 589 845 2889
15898452889
+1207 244 7002
+1 207 244 7002
(589) 845-2889
+1(589) 845-2889
1(589) 845-2889';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 589-845-2889
    [1] => (589)-845-2889
    [2] => 589.845.2889
    [3] => 589 845 2889
    [4] => 5898452889
    [5] => (589) 845 2889
    [6] => 1(589) 845 2889
    [7] => +1(589) 845 2889
    [8] => 1589 845 2889
    [9] => 1 589 845 2889
    [10] => 15898452889
    [11] => +1207 244 7002
    [12] => +1 207 244 7002
)
```

Comment: How do I use this with `preg_match_all()` like in my question? Because it's currently returning NULL for `$result[0]`

Comment: @user627341 See this php demo https://3v4l.org/io1cm

Comment: For some strange unknown reason, your demo only works on the link you sent. Doesn't work anywhere else, just returns an empty array or a single value at best. Still trying to figure it out, may be a trivial issue.

Comment: @user627341 Can you send me a https://3v4l.org/ link with your code that is not working?

Comment: That's what I'm saying.. it only works on that 3v4l.org interpreter. Doesn't work anywhere else. Tried it on https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com and on my personal shared server.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5da746b720d91298b97ab8fa6cc136ed1b8ce5fb -that's the other link

Comment: @user627341 That is peculiar, let me check

Comment: @user627341 It works adding `\s*` at the end, but the multiline anchors should just work. I will try to find the reason. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eb7a36b2cea233c41ab8a865c962e0498a3ce31d

Comment: Awesome. Kindly extend the expression to support formats (589) 845-2889, +1(589) 845-2889 and 1(589) 845-2889 as well if it wouldn’t be too much trouble. Your solution is excellent! Many thanks 

Comment: @user627341 In that case you can shorted the expression using just a single capture group `^(?:\+?1\h*)?(?:(\()?\d{3}(?(1)\))[-. ]?\d{3}[-. ]?\d{4})$`  See https://regex101.com/r/mf7u9I/1

Comment: Doesn't work on `preg_match_all()` on my server and other interpreters ..  perhaps a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50338413/preg-match-all-not-working-in-php-but-successfully-tested-in-an-online-regex-tes ... probably a bug with PHP or PCRE engine.

Comment: @user627341 You might also match an optional carriage return like http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e75fc2d14e1ac18166daafe809639d3cf8926f17 or using that mentioned fix http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c2c09796f6c98a416d9fa3bc83dd7663e236252c

Comment: Works perfectly now. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative approach:**

You can convert all different types to 1 common syntax delimited by say `.`.
Now, you can try for 2 checks.

- If all are digits and the length is 10 or 11.
- OR if it follows the format of `+1.207.333.4444` or `207.333.4444` or `+1(207).333.4444` or `(207).333.4444`.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

function isValid($str){
    $str = preg_replace('/[.\-\s]/','.',$str);
    return preg_match('/^\d{10,11}$/', $str) === 1 || 
           preg_match('/^((\+?\d)?\.?(\d{3}|\(\d{3}\)))\.(\d{3})\.(\d{4})$/', $str) === 1;
}
```

[**Online Demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/07ad4898fccbd9b557c60f4ca479a3611390c037)

**Suggestion:**

Instead of giving a simple textbox on the UI, give 3-4 blocks delimited by some text, say `-` or `.`. This way, processing them on the backend or adding javascript validation becomes easy.

```css
.input_ph{
 width:35px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<span>+</span><input type="textbox" class="input_ph" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span>-</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span>(</span><input type="textbox" class="input_ph" />
<span>)</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span>-</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="textbox" class="input_ph" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span>-</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="textbox" class="input_ph" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fresh perspective. Very much appreciated.